Django - Pagination doesn't work for the last page
In my website I want to showcase the wines with pagination, 9 pages per page (let's assume we have 22 wines). The wines are stored in the admin interface, each wine with fields like name, type, description and ImageField for uploading their respective images. However, when I click on the third(last) page, the following page is showing:

ValueError at /page-name/
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/page-name/?page=3
Django Version: 5.0.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Location: [path].venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py, line 41, in _require_file
Raised during:  [app-name].views.wines_page_red

And in the console, I get this warning:
TypeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable
..and bunch of exceptions. I'm new to Django and I don't understand what can cause an issue, as all the images for the respective items are uploaded. Read somewhere that the method I used for pagination can be unstable, so I tried to order the wines by their name, and now the 2nd page gave the same errord. Here is the view, url part and the template:
View:
def wines_page_red(request):
    red_wines_list = Wine.objects.filter(type='Red')
    paginator = Paginator(red_wines_list, 9)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, 'red-wines.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})

Project-level url part:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('[app-name].urls')),

] + static(django.conf.settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=django.conf.settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Settings part:
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT, used for managing stored files.

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / ''

Template:
   <section class="products section-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for wine in page_obj %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 mb-3">
                    <div class="product-thumb">
                        <a href="product-detail.html">
                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ wine.image.url }}" class="img-fluid product-image" alt="">
                        </a>

                        <div class="product-info d-flex">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="product-title mb-0">
                                    <a href="product-detail.html" class="product-title-link">{{ wine.name }}</a>
                                </h5>

                            <p class="product-p">{{ wine.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>


This has nothing to do with the pagination, you apparently have a Wine object where the .image refers to an image you removed.

The thing is that I haven't removed an image. I stored the images one time and that's it. In admin page the images are there. Even when i try to re-upload the image, nothing changes

did you specify an image for all Wines, there is no one with image=None?

Yes uploaded the images for specifically red wines, as for this particular page I filter the wines by type='Red'. Rest will be uploaded in the scope of separate pages. What is confusing me is that only the third page have such issues

well that is probably because there is only one faulty Wine and the fact that it is on the third page is just a coincidence. It could have been on any page.

This has nothing to do with pagination. It simply means there is Wine object where the image does not refer to an (existing) image file.
You can first check if the image is not None:
{% if wine.image %}
  <a href="product-detail.html">
    <img src="{{ wine.image.url }}" class="img-fluid product-image" alt="image of the wine">
  </a>
{% endif %}
You furthermore should of course ensure that the content refers to a real file, otherwise we get 404 when serving the media file.
Normally you don't need the MEDIA_ROOT in the template: the .url normally adds the media prefix itself, given it is configured properly.
You can also filter out Wines without an image:
def wines_page_red(request):
    red_wines_list = Wine.objects.filter(type='Red', image__isnull=False)
    paginator = Paginator(red_wines_list, 9)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'red-wines.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})

Modified the files and somehow it helped, thanks a lot

Not somehow, that's the exact problem, that wine object doesn't have a image, so trying to access image url gives error. But with above code only try to access image url only if image is present in the wine object.
